# @commands.has_any_role() не работает

Tags: python, discord.py

В боте реализовал команду очистки n сообщений. Остаётся дать использовать эту команду только определённым ролям.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["!", "-"], test_guilds=[903992552250810408], sync_commands=True)

high_ranks = ["Owner", "D.Owner", "High Rank"]

@bot.slash_command(description="Очистка n сообщений")
@commands.has_any_role(high_ranks)
async def clear(inter, number: int):
    await inter.channel.purge(limit=number)

    delete = disnake.Embed(description=f"**Сообщения успешно очищены**", color=disnake.Color.green())

    await inter.send(embed=delete, ephemeral=True)
```

**Получаю ошибку:**

```
disnake.ext.commands.errors.MissingAnyRole: You are missing at least one of the required roles: '['Owner', 'D.Owner', 'High Rank']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно прочитал документацию. Чтобы в качестве параметра передать список, нужно его "распаковать". Например: @commands.has_any_role(*high_ranks)